# Listing the largest files on disk in Windows

Tags: windows, filesystems

I'm after a list of the largest files on a windows box, i.e. Not just in one folder, but anywhere on the disk. Is there any easy way of getting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a windows search on you windows drive with "*" joker that mean all file, and specify a minimum size let's say of 40mb, than you'll have every file on you system drive that are larger than 40mb.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 21):

Check out this app: [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info)

This will show you graphically as well as a hierarchy/tree map. This software is free and open source (GPL) and works really well.

Comment: +10! windirstat is awesome

Comment: I have always used Sequoia View, but just installed WinDirStat to take a look at it.  Very nice.  I think Sequoia View lays out the Tree Map a little better and is more responsive.  I do like WinDirStat's ability to select a file type and see it highlighted across the entire drive.

Comment: @Keith Sirmons - Do you know if Sequoia is a branch of WinDirStat? They look very similar and since WinDirStat is open source this is very possible.

Comment: Sequoia View's V1.1 original publish date is 11/9/2000. It was about 5 years ahead of WinDirStat's V1.1.2 release on 7/16/2005.

Answer (score 13):

Install [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/powershell-scripting?view=powershell-6).  Then run this:

```
dir c:\ -recurse -erroraction silentlycontinue | sort length -descending | select -first 20
```

That'll give you back the top 20 largest files on `C:`.

Comment: incredibly useful

Comment: This eats up all the memory and throws an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Great out-of-the-box solution, thanks for posting.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this regularly, you might look at tools like [TreeSize Pro](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/TreeSize-Pro.shtml) or [SizeExplorer](http://www.sizeexplorer.com/ss.htm) (although the latter seems to nob be as recent).

Comment: @Marc-AndreR., Do you mean TreeSize or do you mean SizeExplorer?

Comment: @Pacerier : TreeSize is definitely more recent and maintain than SizeExplorer or WinDirStat. That said, both does the job but I do have a preference for TreeSize. Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

Install [Sequoia View](http://www.win.tue.nl/sequoiaview/)

It will visually show you your large files and large directories.  It makes finding where all your space disappeared very easy.

Free and < 1 Mb in size.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell (extending answer [7768](https://serverfault.com/a/7768/1440)) across multiple drives:

```
 "c","e","f" | dir -path {"$($_):\"} -rec -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | sort -desc Length | select -first 20 | ft FullName
```

Comment: Are you certain that this currently works?

Comment: @Nae Over nine years ago: I can't recall. But the new version definitely does

Comment: Yes it does seem to be working now. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to do this is to type the following into the search box in Windows Explorer:

`* size:gigantic` or if you are after slightly smaller files go for `* size:huge`.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite is Disk Scanner by Steffen Gerlach:

http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/

Standalone freeware, 157K.  Takes a little time to build the report, but the circular graphic is very intuitive and informative.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and it is free: [Folder Size](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Folder-Size/Folder-Size.html)
There is a small tutorial here: [How to List Largest Files & Largest Folders](http://info.mindgems.com/largest-files-largest-folders-list-in-windows/)